# jmeter jdbc variable names query

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, oracle12c

Again more apologies from myself for being a Jmeter newbie - I'm a little stuck with the JDBC requests - I've trawled through the posts on this site for the last 3 hours - but I can't quite find anything relevant (unless I'm missing something).

My environment: Jmeter v2.11, JDK 7, Oracle 12

It's very simple - I have a JDBC Sampler that I need to setup to use the value that is provided by a JDBC PreProcessor.

Essentially I have a JDBCPreProcessor setup to identify the next (new) record's unique reference (call it applicationID)

JDBC PreProcessor Details

Select Statement --> select max(applicationID)+1 from table;

I have a JDBC Sampler setup that I need to use the 'max(applicationID)+1' value (determined by the JDBC preprocessor)

JDBC Sampler Details

Select Statement --> select status from table where applicationID = 'max(applicationID)+1'

I am unsure how to do this.  I have looked at the instructions and a lot of other Jmeter JDBC request posts, but I'm afraid I can't find the relevant info I need.

I did try including adding a 'Variable Name' of 'maxrecordidvar' in the JDBC PreProcessor and set the JDBC Sampler query --> select status from table where applicationID = maxrecordidvar

HOWEVER - this (obviously) didn't work - I get an Oracle error 'ORA-00904: "MAXRECORDIDVAR": invalid identifier'

Again, many apologies if this is a stupid question and many thanks for all/any help anyone can provide!

Comment: I should highlight that I haven't just submitted this query without looking for answers.  I think the RegEx expression extractor or perhaps the User Defined Variables might allow me to do what I need, but I'm still not sure of how to do what I need with these functions - cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have simulated a concept of this using MYSQL, but the test plan is similar.

- JDBC pre processor to get an Integer
- Use that integer in a following JDBC request

First, the JDBC PreProcessor and JDBC Request do not just simply emit to a single variable, but rather expose a few variables based on your name.   For example

- Query : select CAST(RAND() * 242 AS UNSIGNED);
- Variable Name : foo

Which means later on I have access to

- ${foo_#} - the number of rows (which should be 1)
- ${foo_1} - the value in first column row 1

This query only has one column and row, otherwise ${foo_2} would be first column row 2.  More docs at [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

[image]

Second, to use with in my JDBC Request I had to use a Prepared Select Statement.  Passing in ${foo_1} as the Parameter Value and INTEGER as the Parameter Type (I am using mysql).

[image]

I posted a simulated [load test and JMX File](https://www.redline13.com/share/testplan/11683).

Comment: Thankyou!  I have replicated your approach against my database and it works (now the section in the Jmeter Help makes a little more sense now!)  HOWEVER - I am getting an invalid data type error (reported on the JDBC request) when running the test despite the fact that I am using the correct type.  The comment field doesn't allow enough characters so I'm going to have to create a new thread - thanks again Richard - your explanation really helped me understand the help file content as well as getting me further along.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) or [longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) function is easier way of incrementing your "applicationID" variable by one.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for advanced information on different JMeter functions, where to place, how to use them, etc.